# Dependent Pair Types

Tags: types, coq

In software foundations, [Logic in Coq](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis500/current/sf/lf-current/Logic.html), we are introduced to parametrized propositions:

```
Definition is_three (n : nat) : Prop :=
n = 3.
Check is_three.
(* ===> nat -> Prop *)
```

which reminds me of dependent pair types, which from [Reading HoTT in Coq](https://mdnahas.github.io/doc/Reading_HoTT_in_Coq.pdf) we have dependent pair types to be defined:

```
Inductive sigT {A:Type} (P:A -> Type) : Type :=
existT : forall x :A, P x -> sigT P.
```

Can someone explain how are they different and also in Reading HoTT in Coq, it says "Since we haven’t defined propositional equality, we can’t do
much that is interesting here", why can't we do anything interesting without propositional equality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us pretend for now that the HoTT code uses `A -> Prop` instead of `A -> Type`; the difference between the two is orthogonal to your question.

A parametrized proposition `P : A -> Prop` is simply property of elements of the type `A`.  Besides the simple `is_three` proposition above, we can express more complex properties of natural numbers in this fashion.  For instance:

```
Definition even (n : nat) : Prop :=
  exists p, n = 2 * p.

Definition prime (n : nat) : Prop :=
  n >= 2 /\
  forall p q, n = p * q -> p = n \/ p = 1.
```

The type `sigT A P` type allows us to restrict the type `A` to elements that satisfy the property `P`.  For instance, `sigT nat even` is the type of all even numbers, `sigT nat prime` is the type of all prime numbers, etc. In Coq, properties are the more primitive concept, and subset types like `sigT` are a derived concept.

In traditional mathematics, the concepts of property and subset can almost be conflated: saying that 2 is a prime number is equivalent to saying that it belongs to the set of all prime numbers.  In Coq's type theory, this is not quite the case, because being an element of a type is *not* a proposition: you cannot, for instance, state a theorem saying that 2 is an element of `sigT nat prime`.  The following snippet throws an error:

```
Lemma bogus : (2 : {x : nat & prime x}).
(* Error: *)
(* The term "2" has type "nat" while it is expected to have type *)
(*  "{x : nat & prime x}". *)
```

(The `{ ... & ... }` is syntactic sugar for the `sigT` type defined in Coq's standard library.)

The closest we can get is to say that 2 can be extracted from that type:

```
Lemma fixed : exists x : {x : nat & prime x}, 2 = projT1 x.
```

where `projT1` is the function that extracts the first component of the dependent pair.  However, this is much more cumbersome than simply stating that 2 is prime:

```
Lemma prime_two : prime 2.
```

In general, parametrized propositions are more useful in Coq, but there are cases where `sigT` type comes in handy; for instance, when we only care about the elements of a type that satisfy a certain property.  Imagine that you implement a associative map in Coq using a type of binary search trees.  You might begin by defining a type `tree` of *arbitrary* trees:

```
Inductive tree :
| Leaf : tree
| Node : tree -> nat -> nat -> tree -> tree.
```

This type defines a binary tree whose nodes store a key-value pair of natural numbers.  To implement functions for looking up an element, updating a value, etc., using this type, we might maintain the invariant that the keys of the tree are sorted (that is, that the keys on the left subtree are less than the keys of a node, and the opposite for the right subtree).  Since users of this tree will not want to consider trees that do not satisfy this invariant, we might use instead the type `sigT tree well_formed`, where `well_formed : tree -> Prop` expresses the above invariant.  The main advantage is that this simplifies the interface of our library: instead of having a separate lemma saying that the insertion function preserves the invariant, this would be automatically expressed in the type of the insertion function itself; users wouldn't even need to bother arguing that the trees that they construct using the interface respect the invariant.

As for your second question, equality is so fundamental that it is hard to define interesting properties without it.  For instance, the properties `even` and `prime` above are both defined using equality.

Comment: Thanks Arthur! that was a good explanation and has also indirectly shown the difference between `Prop` and `Type` in Coq. Thus, to prove `fixed` Lemma means to find a dependent pair in `{x : nat & prime x}` with its `projT1` equal to 2. Then for the proof of `prime_two`, we use tactics to proof `2 >= 2 /\  forall p q, 2 = p * q -> p = 2 \/ p = 1.`. Is this the right understanding?